# How to create multiple html reports in playwright for multiple spec files ? Kindly assist

Tags: ui-automation, e2e-testing, playwright, browser-automation, playwright-test

I'm fairly new to Playwright, and I'm stuck and unable to generate HTML reports. I'm using basic playwright report (index.html) which gets updated every time in run a different spec file.

Also if I share the index.html file, the other person cannot see any content.

Can someone please help me in creating a separate HTML report based on individual spec files? Also if shared, the report should be viewable.

the below is my config file :

```
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { devices } from '@playwright/test';

    const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
      // globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup.ts'),
      // globalTeardown: require.resolve(''),       //we will use this later
      testDir: './FeatureSpecs',
      /* Maximum time one test can run for. */
      timeout: 130 * 1000,
      expect: {
        /**
         * Maximum time expect() should wait for the condition to be met.
         * For example in `await expect(locator).toHaveText();`
         */
        timeout: 50000
      },
      /* Run tests in files in parallel */
      // fullyParallel: true,
      
      retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
      /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
      workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
      /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
      reporter: 'html',
      use: {
        storageState: './storage/admin.json',
        actionTimeout: 0,
        headless: true,
    
        // baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    
        trace: 'on-first-retry',
      },
    
      /* Configure projects for major browsers */
      projects: [
        {
          name: 'chromium',
          // use: {
          //   ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
          // },
        },
    
      ],
    
      /* Folder for test artifacts such as screenshots, videos, traces, etc. */
      // outputDir: 'test-results/',
    
      /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
      // webServer: {
      //   command: 'npm run start',
      //   port: 3000,
      // },
    };
    
    export default config;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**
I wanted to point out that I'm going down the rabbit hole here just to explain how to generate separate html reports per spec-file. This is not best practice and you should generally let playwright create one single report and execute all tests with one command. That is the idea behind it. You can create 2 projects with different settings that match different test files if some of your tests have to run on slightly different settings.
In your case I would change the reporter settings to something like this and then share the whole `html/` folder:

```
reporter: [[html', { outputFolder: 'html', open: 'never' }],
  ['list']],
```

---

Yes you can do that but I think there's no setting that allows that easily, gotta do some bash magic! Assuming you have some tests that can run in parallel and some that have to be run serially but you want to run them with one command (`npm run test`).

If you have a config that goes something like this:

```
    const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
      // ...
      /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
      reporter: [['junit', { outputFile: `junit/results.xml` }],
      ['html', { outputFolder: `html/`, open: 'never' }],
      ['list']],
      /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
      use: {
        /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
        trace: 'on-first-retry',
        /* Capture screenshot after each test failure. */
        screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
        /* Record video only when retrying a test for the first time. */
        video: 'retain-on-failure',
      },

      /* Folder for test artifacts such as screenshots, videos, traces, etc. */
      outputDir: `${__dirname}/artifacts`,
    };
```

and a `package.json` file like this:

```json
{
  # ...
  "scripts": {
    "codegen": "npx playwright codegen",
    "test": "npm run test-serial; npm run test-parallel",
    "test-parallel": "./run_playwright_tests.sh parallel",
    "test-serial": "./run_playwright_tests.sh serial"
  },
```

you can write a script that goes something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -Eeuo pipefail

mkdir -p junit html artifacts

if [[ $1 == "serial" ]]; then
    echo "Running serial tests"
    find tests/serial/*.spec.ts | xargs -n 1 -P 20 -I{} sh -c \
        'export PLAYWRIGHT_HTML_REPORT="html/$(basename {})"; \
        export PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME="junit/results_$(basename {}).xml"; \
        npx playwright test {} --reporter=junit,html,list'
elif [[ $1 == "parallel" ]]; then
    echo "Running parallel tests"
    PLAYWRIGHT_HTML_REPORT="html/parallel_tests" PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME="junit/results_parallel_tests.xml" \
    npx playwright test tests/parallel/*.spec.ts --reporter=junit,html,list
else
    echo "$1 is not a valid option"
    exit 1
fi
```

The magic lies in the variables `PLAYWRIGHT_HTML_REPORT` and `PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME`, check the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#html-reporter) for additional info.

Now it's also easy to add this stuff, if running in the CI, to the job artifacts. Here's my example for Gitlab:

```yaml
run_your_test:
  # ...
  script:
    - npm run test
    - cp -r your/test/dir/results results
  artifacts:
    name: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_JOB_NAME}
    expire_in: 5 days
    paths:
      - results/html
    reports:
      junit:
        - results/junit/results_*.xml
    when: always
```

**EDIT:**
I noticed that the approach with the variables is very limited (other settings from the global config get ignored when using them), so I opted for modifying the `playwright.config.ts` on every run instead:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p junit html artifacts

reset_playwright_settings () {
    echo "Settings will be changed back to the defaults"
    sed -i "s/junit\/results.*.xml/junit\/results.xml/g" playwright.config.ts
    sed -i "s/outputFolder: 'html.*',/outputFolder: 'html',/g" playwright.config.ts
}

modify_playwright_settings () {
    echo "Settings will be changed for $1"
    sed -i "s/junit\/results.*.xml/junit\/results_$1.xml/g" playwright.config.ts
    sed -i "s/outputFolder: 'html.*',/outputFolder: 'html\/$1',/g" playwright.config.ts
}
export -f modify_playwright_settings

if [[ $1 == "serial" ]]; then
    echo "Running serial tests"
    find tests/serial/*.spec.ts | xargs -I{} bash -c 'modify_playwright_settings $(basename {}); npx playwright test {}'
elif [[ $1 == "parallel" ]]; then
    echo "Running parallel tests"
    modify_playwright_settings "parallel_tests"
    npx playwright test tests/parallel/*.spec.ts
else
    echo "$1 is not a valid option"
    exit 1
fi

reset_playwright_settings
```

and I call my script like this (in the `package.json`):

```json
{   
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "test": "npm run test-serial; npm run test-parallel",
        "test-parallel": "./run_playwright_tests.sh parallel",
        "test-serial": "./run_playwright_tests.sh serial"
    }
}
```